# How to restrict react Component to Re-rendering,

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I am passing functions to my child component. And I am using React.memo to restrict compoenent from re-rendering. But My component rerenders when parent re-renders. I tried to check why this is happening by using useEffect on all the props and I get to this point that my functions are causing compoenent to re-renders.

```
// my functions

const scrollToView = (index) => {
  if (scrollRef && scrollRef.current && scrollRef.current[index]) {
    scrollRef.current[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
   }
};

const scrollToReportView = (reportIndex) => {
  if (scrollToReportRef && scrollToReportRef.current && 
      scrollToReportRef.current[reportIndex]) {
      scrollToReportRef.current[reportIndex].scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }

.......
function LeftNav({
  scrollToView, //function
  scrollToReportView, //function
  reports, //object
}) {



  useEffect(() => {
     console.log('scrollToView')
  }, [scrollToView])



  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('scrollToReportView')
  }, [scrollToReportView])
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('reports')
  }, [reports])

  return (
    <div>{'My Child Component'}</div>
  );
}

export default memo(LeftNav);

And this is how my left nav is being called

 <LeftNav
   scrollToView={(index) => scrollToView(index)}
   scrollToReportView={(repIndex)=> scrollToReportView(repIndex)}
   reports={reports}
 />
```

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: Why does your component updating matter? Is there a performance issue you've already measured?

Comment: @JatinParmar I have updated question with code

Comment: @AKX yes I have performance issues in my application.

Comment: and how LeftNav is called?

Comment: If the effects are run on every update of the component, it means those functions aren't properly memoized and their identities keep changing. You will need to show how you use LeftNav, and in particular the values for those props.

Comment: @JatinParmar updated question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
 <LeftNav
   scrollToView={(index) => scrollToView(index)}
   scrollToReportView={(repIndex)=> scrollToReportView(repIndex)}
   reports={reports}
 />
```

you're creating new anonymous functions every time you render the `LeftNav` component, so memoization does absolutely nothing.
Just

```
<LeftNav
  scrollToView={scrollToView}
  scrollToReportView={scrollToReportView}
  reports={reports}
/>
```

instead (assuming those functions are stable by identity (e.g. are declared outside the component or are properly `React.useCallback`ed or `React.useMemo`ed).

In other words, if your component is currently

```
function Component() {
  // ...
  const scrollToView = (index) => {
    if (scrollRef && scrollRef.current && scrollRef.current[index]) {
      scrollRef.current[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  };

  const scrollToReportView = (reportIndex) => {
    if (scrollToReportRef && scrollToReportRef.current && scrollToReportRef.current[reportIndex]) {
      scrollToReportRef.current[reportIndex].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <LeftNav
      scrollToView={(index) => scrollToView(index)}
      scrollToReportView={(repIndex) => scrollToReportView(repIndex)}
      reports={reports}
    />,
  );
}
```

it needs to be something like

```
function Component() {
  // ...
  const scrollToView = React.useCallback((index) => {
    if (scrollRef?.current?.[index]) {
      scrollRef.current[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }, []);

  const scrollToReportView = React.useCallback((reportIndex) => {
    if (scrollToReportRef?.current?.[reportIndex]) {
      scrollToReportRef.current[reportIndex].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return (<LeftNav scrollToView={scrollToView} scrollToReportView={scrollToReportView} reports={reports} />);
}
```

so the `scrollToView` and `scrollToReportView` functions have stable identities.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I have tried by calling LeftNav as you mentioned but that did not work for me. But As you mentioned below, my fiunctions are inside the parent compoent so I guess I need to memoize these functione to avoid re-rendering.